# How to add a custom event on legend click

Tags: angular, chart.js

I'm trying to add a custom legend event to my pie chart.
I want to keep the default behaviour (hide/show data) but I want to add a call to an EventEmitter.

For now my code is like that:

```
  @Output() legendClick: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();

  public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
      onClick: function(evt, item) {
        console.log(this);
        // // this.legendClick.emit(item.index) <= i want to do that
        Chart.defaults.pie.legend.onClick.call(this, evt, item)
     },
    },
    title: {text: '', display: true}
  };
```

I don't know how to call my event emmitter.

If I change the onClick function to an arrow function I loose the context to call the default onClick event.

Comment: How about using `bind` of javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bind()` to bind context to a function.

```
public pieChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
      onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this, event, item)
    },
    title: {text: '', display: true}
  };

  handleClick(ev, item): void {
     this.legendClick.emit(item.index)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try it and i got the following error :                                         core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: @mathieulavergne I edited the answer. Please try one more time.

Comment: Still got an error: ERROR ReferenceError: item is not defined. I am not really familiar with bind(), i will read about it !

Comment: @mathieulavergne try to log `item`. Do you get anything when invoke `handleClick` method?

Comment: I see `onClick` event handler takes two parameters, so try to adjust handler like so `this.handleClick.bind(this, event, item)`. Hope it helps.